# Is it possible to make gdb break the first it runs anything inside a specific file?

Tags: gdb

That is ,when we don't know which function inside a file is called,can we make it break without knowing more details?

Comment: Does that mean you don't have the source code of this file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the `rbreak` command. Just specify the exact file you wish to monitor and a regex. So, for all functions in a given file :

```
rbreak file.c:.
```